# Scraping image inside canvas with RSelenium

Tags: r, image, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to get the main image on [this](https://archives.landes.fr/arkotheque/visionneuse/visionneuse.php?arko=YTo3OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMjItMTAtMTgiO3M6MTA6InR5cGVfZm9uZHMiO3M6MTE6ImFya29fc2VyaWVsIjtzOjQ6InJlZjEiO3M6MToiNCI7czo0OiJyZWYyIjtzOjM6IjE3MyI7czoyMjoiZm9yY2VfbnVtX2ltYWdlX2RlcGFydCI7aTozNDA7czoxNjoidmlzaW9ubmV1c2VfaHRtbCI7YjoxO3M6MjE6InZpc2lvbm5ldXNlX2h0bWxfbW9kZSI7czo0OiJwcm9kIjt9) website

The problem is that the main image is loaded via the HTML canvas tag. When I inspect the source code, the image is loaded in here, with no information on any file:

```
<canvas id="image1" class="mesImages ui-draggable" style="position: fixed; width: …ransform: rotate(0deg);" title="" tabindex="-1" width="359" height="542">
```

Is it possible to use RSelenium (and not Python) to get the image in `.png` or `.jpg`?

Answer (score 2):

Gathering links with RSelenium

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = free_port())
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://archives.landes.fr/arkotheque/visionneuse/visionneuse.php?arko=YTo3OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMjItMTAtMTgiO3M6MTA6InR5cGVfZm9uZHMiO3M6MTE6ImFya29fc2VyaWVsIjtzOjQ6InJlZjEiO3M6MToiNCI7czo0OiJyZWYyIjtzOjM6IjE3MyI7czoyMjoiZm9yY2VfbnVtX2ltYWdlX2RlcGFydCI7aTozNDA7czoxNjoidmlzaW9ubmV1c2VfaHRtbCI7YjoxO3M6MjE6InZpc2lvbm5ldXNlX2h0bWxfbW9kZSI7czo0OiJwcm9kIjt9")
accept <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="licence_clic_bouton_accepter"]')
accept$clickElement()
more <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#arkoVision_barToggleButton_bottom")
more$clickElement()

content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

links <- content %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_elements(".imgThumb_container") %>% 
  html_children() %>% 
  html_attr("rel") %>% 
  .[!is.na(.)]

> links %>% head()
[1] "https://archives.landes.fr/arkotheque/visionneuse/img_prot.php?i=13a087d1f5.jpg"
[2] "https://archives.landes.fr/arkotheque/visionneuse/img_prot.php?i=2159e78416.jpg"
[3] "https://archives.landes.fr/arkotheque/visionneuse/img_prot.php?i=65786a44b1.jpg"
[4] "https://archives.landes.fr/arkotheque/visionneuse/img_prot.php?i=702fbd57fa.jpg"
[5] "https://archives.landes.fr/arkotheque/visionneuse/img_prot.php?i=9c4421d51e.jpg"
[6] "https://archives.landes.fr/arkotheque/visionneuse/img_prot.php?i=a4b68fd913.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. That's very helpful ! But when I try to download those images (for example : download.file(links[278],'registre.jpg', mode = 'wb')), I get an error message stating "In download.file(links[278], "y.jpg", mode = "wb") :
  cannot open URL 'https://archives.landes.fr/arkotheque/visionneuse/img_prot.php?i=5a2162e5ff.jpg': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'". Any idea abour how I might resolve that ?